# Eclpse Kepler get blocked before it closes. How to avoid this annoying issue?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

I can't work properly. When I edit some files or change a tab in Eclipse or any other thing the program get dark a while without letting me do anything, and just after a while it closes.

Is there a way to clean de project config files or something to avoid this problem?

**System description:**

- Ubuntu 13.10
- Eclipse Kepler
- Tomcat 7.0.50

Comment: Do you have enough memory?

Comment: 3 gb Ram, it is a old pc

Comment: Should be enough.  There are several other steps to take to identify what happens (most likely then a JVM issue or a GTK problem) but if you went back to XP this is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when one or more system resource (usually CPU) is critically low.  In fact, it's not just Eclipse that has problems when these symptoms appear.

To recover, be sure to refresh the projects in the workspace.  You may have to re-import projects that were created just before the implosion.

As for the problem, look to see what else is running on the system.  You say this happens when you edit a file, it could be that the builders for a particular file type are running out of resources when you save, but that's probably unlikely.

Comment: I changed to Lubuntu x32, same as before. I reinstall Ubuntu x64 with the same result. So I decide to move back again, to windows xp!